# Jquery time picker not working in the usercontrol

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

When i use the below code in webpage (.aspx file), it works fine; but when I use the below in a user control (.ascx file) it does not work.

How to fix this? Do i have to do any modifications in the masterpage.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ExclusionSwipeCardRequest.ascx.cs" Inherits="ExclusionSwipeCardRequest" %>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../App_Themes/LMSTheme/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#txtFromDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy', changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });   
});
</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtFromDate" MaxLength="10" runat="server" autocomplete="off" ToolTip="Enter From Date"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might suggest that your paths have changed, which would mean that the `src`/`href` value of the script/CSS imports are wrong.

Rather than using relative paths that jump *up* directories, you could try qualifying the path from the root of the website (starting the URL with a forward-slash `/`), such that:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/Scripts/App_Themes/LMSTheme/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
```

Obviously if there are any paths between the root and the `Scripts` folder, you would need to specify it, for example:

```
src="/MyIntermediatePath/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"
```

Also worth mentioning is that although control ID prefixing can be managed (even turned off in .NET4), generally server-side controls have IDs in the page that have been concocted by their parent container, such as:

```
txtFromDate -> ctl001_txtFromDate
```

If you weren't using a server-side control in the page initially, you might want to check you haven't introduced an issue with jQuery finding the control in the rendered page.

Comment: Should he be importing the scripts in the ASCX at all? Shouldn't that be handed back to the page e.g. with [ScriptManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398863.aspx)?

Comment: @Rup That's a different matter, I guess; you're correct (IMO), but for the sake of the problem at hand, this may well help solve it. Don't really want to start a debate over _where_ these files _should_ be referenced.

Comment: No it is not working......the problem is in usercontrol only.....how to use in usercontrol.....

Comment: i want to use this is one in jquery a? eg $("#ctl001_txtFromDate").datepicker(

Comment: Well, not really, but you could try `$("input[type='text']:eq(0)")`. This will grab the first text input on the page and should suit this purpose, though it is not robust and open to failure when page structure changes.

Comment: how to give in my jquery it is not working in the usercontrol

Comment: i have used like this is not working  $('input[name="txtFromDate"]').datepicker();

Answer (score 1):

the id for the textbox is not correct,

try

```
$("#<%=txtFromDate.ClientID%>").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy', changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });
```

instead of

```
$("#txtFromDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy', changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });
```

Comment: i am getting error 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' does not contain a definition for 'ClientId'

Comment: sorry, it's ClientID capital D in the end

Comment: umm, ClientID is a property of all types of controls, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx

Comment: how are you registering the control on the page?

Comment: $("#<%=txtFromDate.ClientID%>").datepicker i used this but nt working

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the src url in your script references. it's relative to the page's location where control is used, not the control itself.

I recommend you put your css/script links in the [master]page instead of user control.